# redirection to different page after login

Tags: php, mysql

how can i redirect user to different page depending upon a situation. Like if user have been redirected to login page from product page after clicking a product, send them to checkout with product detail after successful logging. and if they want to upload a product then to upload dashboard on login.

Comment: i want to send user to different location accordingly. Like if a user clicks on BUY button without logging in they will be sent to login page and after successful login they will be redirected to checkout page, by default if user tries to login in with login button... successful login will send them to index.similarly if they hit publish or read button without logging, to publish or reader page after login. not to index every time as they login.

Comment: i want to send user to different location accordingly. Like if a user clicks on BUY button without logging in they will be sent to login page and after successful login they will be redirected to checkout page, by default if user tries to login in with login button... successful login will send them to index.similarly if they hit publish or read button without logging, to publish or reader page after login. not to index every time as they login. And one thing user won't login from checkout page.So, i guess  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) is no good to me.